# Who is "Dao" in this quote from Laozi's Tao Te Ching?

Tags: meaning, quote-source, chinese-language, dao-de-jing, laozi

I found the following quote [here](https://javascript.info/ninja-code):

> The Dao hides in wordlessness. Only the Dao is well begun and well completed.
>
> -- Laozi, *Dàodé Jīng / Tao Te Ching*

What is the exact meaning and context of this quote? I was curious to know what is meant by the word **Dao** in the context of the given quote.

Comment: What translation are you basing your quote on? Please provide a link to it if it's available online. Or give me a chapter number. The translation I've found freely available online is [this one by James Legge](http://classics.mit.edu/Lao/taote.1.1.html)

Comment: https://javascript.info/ninja-code I found the quote here.

Comment: I've edited your question to ask about the exact source of this quote, using the [tag:quote-identification] tag, as well as its meaning. Knowing the specific source and context will surely help in figuring out the meaning. Who knows, maybe the quote isn't even accurate, since it's not reliably sourced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **Dao** is the more recent translation of the word formerly rendered **Tao**.  The original Chinese term, in ordinary usage, means the Way.  However, in Daoism (Taoism), it became a philosophical concept of great depth, pervasive to the philosophy, and one of its teaching is that

> The Dao which can be explained is not the true Dao.

Therefore, the Dao "exists in wordlessness" -- it exists though it can not be explained in words -- and because it is the fundamental root of things, it is complete in itself, always beginning and ending things properly.  More or less.

This will get deep into philosophy if you want to consider it further.

Comment: "Dao" is not a more recent *translation*, it is the pinyin *transcription* of 道; "tao" is the Wade-Giles transcription. Both transcription are intended to render the character's *pronunciation*, not its meaning.